# How can I access the store address in a Shopify theme file (.liquid extension file)?

Tags: shopify

I have set store address for a Shopify site, as seen in the screenshot below. Now I want to access this address in a theme file (.liquid file). How can I do this?

[image: Shopify Store address in General settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access those attributes. The [shop object](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/shop/?ref=microapps) gives you the following attributes but the store address is not available yet.

```
shop.collections_count
shop.currency
shop.description
shop.domain
shop.email
shop.enabled_payment_types
shop.metafields
shop.money_format
shop.money_with_currency_format
shop.name
shop.password_message
shop.permanent_domain
shop.products_count
shop.types
shop.url
shop.vendors
shop.locale
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can get the shop's address accessing 'shop' liquid object.

Ex: **{{ shop.address.summary }}**

Please refer the [shopify official cheat sheet](https://www.shopify.com/partners/shopify-cheat-sheet?shpxid=567e048b-6295-4870-E79E-1A754256B8E7) for more info. Check the shop object in there.